# I have a Floating Action Button on my site but there are problems

Tags: html, css, mobile, floating-action-button

I used HTML and CSS (Material Design Blog help) to design the object. The code works (MS Edge & Chrome) on the desktop, the mobile version (MS Edge & Chrome) the button lets the text in front of a Parallax panel show through and it goes behind only one of my images. One the desktop I think it just don't have the same problems because of positioning (no words to go through and the image is not inline with the FAB.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<a href="tel:9788888888" class="fab" >Call</a>
```

The site had it placed in a div:
`<div class="fab">Call</div>`
But I needed it to be a link without using JQuery so that it can access the phone.
The CSS code used (including the commented out items,):

```
   .fab {
   width: 90px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color: #8BC34A;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 #666;
  /* transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;*/
 
   font-size: 40px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 70px;
 
   position: fixed;
   right:  50px;
   bottom: 50px;
}
 
.fab:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 6px 14px 0 #666;
   /*transform: scale(1.05);*/
   color: black;
}
```

I just want to keep it on top of everything if possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you put your question in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? this will help us figure out what exact issue you're running into

Comment: did you try to give it `z-index` value?

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to change the z-index value to a number higher than that of the parallax which was 55, I tried 60 and 100 but I still get the same problem on the phone (on other screens the text is not under the Fab) Changing the position to absolute made it disappear all together. I only gave the part of the code that was relevant on both the HTML and the CSS, I don't think there was a way to make it any more minimalistic than I did, if I added something that was not necessary (code wise) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `z-index` value that is greater than the main content, 0 is the default value. You may also consider `position: absolute` for a locked-in-place CTA button.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp